# veracrypt volume (FAT) created on Mac OS, placed in Box cloud, is empty on Windows 7

Tags: truecrypt, box.com

I created a veracrypt FAT volume on my MacOS (10.9.5) in the 'Box Sync' folder

I placed a jpeg file in this volume and then dismounted

I have a Windows 7 PC that has Box Sync, which I used to sync.

I mounted the volume created in step#1, on the Windows 7 PC, but it shows as empty (nothing inside).

Encryption = Serpent(Twofish(AES))

No hidden volumes

Any idea why Windows 7 thinks the volume is empty despite the Box Sync?

Comment: Are you using hidden volumes in your Veracrypt File ?  If so, did you enter the password to the non-hidden volume, while your data is in the hidden volume ?

Comment: no hidden volumes. Just one volume (FAT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt does not update container timestamp on dismount, and only original (empty) container got synced. You need to touch the container after dismount so Box Sync will notice the change and resyncronize.

Comment: do you think this is worthy of an enhancement/fix in VeraCrypt? I think they should fix this otherwise it reduces the effectiveness of encrypting files in the cloud if you are accessing the cloud from multiple platforms. Do you know where I can file a bug/enchancement?

Comment: IIRC, on the original TrueCrypt website it was listed as a feature: powerful adversary like state or mafia cannot know/prove that you accessed the cryptocontainer recently (unless they have taken a full dump of that file before and after the access, e.g. by secretly breaking into your home). It may help for plausible deniability, e.g. putting alongside a script which contains dd from /dev/urandom to that file. (If alleged dd output has slightly distant creation/modification times, this legend falls apart.)